# LXML: KeyError: '@' - element.find('./@attrname')

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I don't know how but `element.find('./@attrname')` raises `KeyError: '@'`

**code**

```
    import lxml.etree as ET
    with open(self.filepaths[0]) as f:
        root = ET.parse(f)
        root = root.getroot()

        namespaces = {'xmlns': 'http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml',
                      "xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}
        items = root.findall('.//product', namespaces)

        for item in items:
            name = item.find('./description/short_desc[@xml:lang="pol"]', namespaces).text

            try:
                desc = item.find('./description/long_desc[@lang="pol"]', namespaces).text
            except AttributeError:
                desc = None

            code = item.find('./@code_on_card',namespaces)
```

I'm trying to get `code_on_card` attribute from `<product type="xxx" id="xxx" vat="23.0" code_on_card="xxx">`

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple - I used `.find` instead of `.xpath`.

EDIT:

Then you have to get text using **xpath**: `element.xpath('.//element/text())[0]`